# Get alpha component of bitmap, C#

Tags: c#, image, colors, bitmap, alpha

I am trying to get the alpha component of a bitmap. Using the `GetPixel` method just gets the rgb, and the alpha components are all 255 (opaque). Here is what I have tried:

```
System.Drawing.Color tmp;

int rows = bitmap.Width;
int cols = bitmap.Height;

string[,] alphaMatrix = new string[rows,cols];
for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
    {
        tmp = bitmap.GetPixel(i, j);
        alphaMatrix[i, j] = tmp.ToArgb().ToString();
    }
}
return alphaMatrix;
```

Edit:
Originally my image is a `BitmapImage`, that I convert to a `System.Drawing.Bitmap`. I am using this method:

```
private System.Drawing.Bitmap BitmapImageToBitmap(BitmapImage bitmapImage)
{
    using (MemoryStream outStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        BitmapEncoder enc = new BmpBitmapEncoder();
        enc.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(bitmapImage));
        enc.Save(outStream);
        System.Drawing.Bitmap bitmap = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(outStream);

        return new System.Drawing.Bitmap(bitmap);
    }
}
```

Comment: Could be as simple as the bitmap not having an alpha because it is a 24-bpp image.

Comment: I edited my post. Could it be when I convert the BitmapImage to a Bitmap? How can I change the bpp?

Comment: Now, did you check your original image's pixel format??